# Export mysql database to excel

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpexcel

I have been trying to export the content of mysql database to excel using the script below to no avail. I must be doing somethign wrong:

```
$getExcel = "SELECT name, age, course, city FROM person";
$res = mysql_query($getExcel);


/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);

date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

/** PHPExcel */
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';


// Create new PHPExcel object
echo date('H:i:s') . " Create new PHPExcel object\n";
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

if(!$res){
    die("Error");
}
$col = 0; 
$row = 0; 
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) { 
    foreach($row as $key=>$value) { 
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $value); 
        $col++; 
    } 
    $row++; 
} 

// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

// Save Excel 2007 file
echo date('H:i:s') . " Write to Excel2007 format\n";
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('record.xlsx');
```

What I'm I doing wrong please?

Comment: Aside from the fact that $row should start at 1 rather than 0, what's the actual problem? Is the file being generated? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Keep it simple, just create an `html` file in your code with a `table` in it, and save it as `.xls`, then open it with excel. it's a dirty dirty hack but it works if all you need to do is export some data to excel.  It won't an entire whole system...

Comment: @Yaniro - it's a dirty trick that brings up a warning message in most new versions of MS EXcel - not the greatest user experience in the world... I'd consider it pretty unprofessional if I was the user opening that file

Comment: @Mark Baker, The file is not being generated and i am not getting any errors either. I can connect to the db and the query does return data - just doesn't generate the excel file. I have tried changing $row to 1 but no joy. I also tried changing $col to 1... No success.

Comment: The file should be generated in the directory on the server where the script is running... double check user permissions for that folder... or try saving to php://output with appropriate headers (and without any echoes in the code) to download it directly from your browser

Comment: You are using the same variable `$row` in two different contexts ... one as a counter, one as the mysql row ... That's bound to cause issues ... You think you're passing an int to PHPExcel, but you're not ...

Comment: @Mark Baker. I have tried saving tp php://output with appropriate headers. It generates the file and prompts a download but the content of the file is scambled characters.

Comment: another workaround: the Office XML-Formats are not very difficult as you can see here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats. Some days ago I created an Excel export by creating an xml-structure and saved it with xls-extension.

Comment: ARe there any obvious error messages in among those "scrampled characters" or any spaces at the beginning or end of the file? What happens when you try to open it in Excel (or Libre/Open Office Calc or Gnumeric)?

Comment: The OP has chosen to use a library that does the job, so why so many comments telling him that he should generate in a different format and then tell porky pies to Excel

Comment: @MarkBaker, as i've specified in my answer, it IS a dirty trick to be used only to open tabular data in excel and then save it from the application itself, not to be used as a basis for a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your issue is, likely, that you're using the variable `$row` in two different contexts ... try this:

```
$row = 1; 
while($mrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($res)) { 
    $col = 0; 
    foreach($mrow as $key=>$value) { 
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValueByColumnAndRow($col, $row, $value); 
        $col++; 
    } 
    $row++; 
}
```

Comment: Alright, this generates the excel but the columns are not aligned. E.g. if the first record starts at A1, the second start at C2, then G3 instead of all records to start at column A. Any ideas guys?

Comment: $col = 0; should be inside the while loop, immediately before the foreach() loop

Comment: You twuo guys are amazing. I'm eternally grateful!!